# Vertex Groups assignment from Makehuman mesh

Tags: mesh, vertices, vertex-groups, makehuman

I have imported a mesh from Makehuman, and I started creating and assigning vertex groups using the "c" key and choosing the vertices. The problem is that many vertices are missed from the selection and not assigned to a vertex group. I don't know how to assign every single vertex to form `n` vertex_groups in a fast way without missing any vertices? Because missing vertices cause me a problem and also it took me hours doing this.

What I want to acheive is to have different vertex groups. So I don't know how to do this in an accurate way, as I use the ctrl+b and ctrl+c to select vertices and create the 26 different vertex groups but first I don't know how to do this so that the right side is equal to the left side, for example right hand vertices equals the left hand ones so that they are symmetrical. The second problem is, when I export the vertices, I find that the some vertices are not assigned to any vertex group and others are assigned to more than one. I also want to link the mesh with the armature and give weight to the different vertex groups. So if anyone could please advise.

Comment: Why do you miss vertices in your selection? You should add a screenshot to illustrate the issue. Circle select would highlight each selected vertex. When you assign them to vertex group none of them should get lost.

Comment: What about using weight painting rather than selecting vertices?

Comment: @stacker the question has been edited with files and everything provided. SO if you could please advise

Comment: @gandalf3 the question has been edited with files and everything provided. SO if you could please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Selection

You could assign the vertex groups (VGs) starting from a hand make sure that you name the groups with suffixes e.g ForeArm.L, ForeArm.R (this is required to let Blender know which vertex groups correspond).

[image]

Invert the selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> 
[image]

Deselect (<kbd>MMB</kbd> while in *Select Mode*) all vertices which should not belong to the ForeArm VG. Note that you can also use already assigned VGs to help exact deselecting (especially for the head and upper body parts).

Repeat this process for all VG assignments on one side.

[image]

### Mirroring (using Mirror Modifier)

Finally use *Mirror Vertex Group* to copy the VG data from one side to the other, Note that empty VGs with matching names are required.

[image]

The mirror isn't very intuitive due to its prerequisites, therefore I suggest first to watch the video and first try it with a single VG:

[Video Mirror Vertex Groups (Spanish)](http://vimeo.com/25485562)

From the docs of [Mirror Modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror)

> Vertex Groups 
>   When this button is enabled, the Mirror modifier will
>   try to mirror existing vertex groups. A very nice feature, but that
>   has quite specific prerequisites. First, the vertex groups you want to
>   mirror must be named following the usual left/right pattern (i.e.
>   suffixed by something like “.R”, “.right”, “.L”, et cetera). Next, you
>   must have the “mirrored” groups already existing (i.e. same names
>   suffixed by the “other side”) and completely empty (no vertex assigned
>   to it), else it won’t work. Usually, the mirrored copies of the
>   vertices of a group remain in this group. Once this option is
>   activated, all groups following the rules described above will only be
>   valid on the original object – the mirrored copy will put these same
>   vertices into the “mirror” group. Very handy with armatures, for
>   example: you just model half of your object, carefully rig it with
>   half of your armature, and just let the Mirror modifier build the
>   other half. Just be sure to put your Armature modifier(s) after the
>   Mirror one. A final word about multi-axes mirror: in these cases, the
>   “direct”, “first level” copies get the mirrored groups, the copies of
>   copies (“second level”) get the original groups, et cetera.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how to avoid missing vertices and also avoid selecting same vertex to be in two different Vgroups? like in your answer for example, after I selected the forearm.L, and moving to the lowerarm.L how did you precisely selected the vertices of the lowerarm.L without missing any empty vertices and also without duplicating a vertex in two vgroups?

Comment: I used box select in vertex mode, by inversion you can get sure that none of the previously selected vertices is still selected. When in solid mode make sure that you switched the _limit to visible option_ off. Think of sets when you deselect VGs.

Comment: how to map or connect these vertex groups with the bones in the armature? and when I do ctrl+p (automatic weighting it creates different vertex groups with different names)

Comment: If your wanting to do automatic weighting, make sure you parent the rig and model before you start manually editing the vertex groups, then modify the groups that automatic weighting creates.